# Is efficiency of Switch worth using it for nested conditionals instead of if, else?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Im writing a program in java and part of it has to evaluate cleavages in a protein sequence.
I have to evaluate if the cleavage happens at certain groups on either end which results in if, else/elseif statements with either annoying logicals in several places, nesting, or just several "if"s and/or "else"s. I've used switch as an alternative to having to evaluate several "if"s and logicals (&&, ||) each time a cleavage happens (this loop will iterate literally MILLIONS of times, possible tens or hundreds of millions).

heres the chunk of code:
-.getSeq() gets a string representing the sequence of a protein
-startPos and endPos are the indices of the cleavages on either end
-sorry if the if statement lines are broken into multiple lines or convoluted, but that's kind of my case and point about the logicals.

```
/**0: non-tryptic, 1: half-tryptic, 2: fully tryptic**************/
public boolean checkPep(int trypticity){
    boolean evaluator = false;
    int prev = 0;
    if (startPos != 0){
        prev = 1;
    }
    switch(trypticity){
/**do not check cleavage if peptide can be non-tryptic*/
    case 0:
        evaluator = true;
        break;
/***half-tryptic*/
/**check if either the start OR end cleavage is tryptic*/
    case 1:
        switch(protein.getSeq().charAt(startPos-prev)){
        case 'K':
            evaluator = true;
            break;
        case 'R':
            evaluator = true;
            break;
        default :
            switch(protein.getSeq().charAt(endPos)){
            case 'K':
                evaluator = true;
                break;
            case 'R':
                evaluator = true;
                break;
            default:
                evaluator = false;
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
/**fully tryptic*/
/**if first cleavage is tryptic, check end cleavage*/
/**evaluator = true IFF both cleavages are tryptic*******/
    case 2:
        if(((protein.getSeq().charAt(startPos-1)) == 'K') || ((protein.getSeq().charAt(startPos-1)) == 'R')){
            if(((protein.getSeq().charAt(endPos)) == 'K') || ((protein.getSeq().charAt(endPos)) == 'R')){
                evaluator = true;
            }else{
                evaluator = false;
            }
        }else{
            evaluator = false;
        }
        break;
    }
    return evaluator;
}
```

Comment: lolz, OP said "cleavage"

Comment: Profiling tools can help you time this, if you are that concerned.  Also, in general, compilers are pretty good at optimizing this kind of code -- even your many repeated calls of `protein.getSeq()` :)

Comment: Yep, enzymatic cleavage of polypeptides. Not too titillating. I wonder if you would be better off using a HashMap here. It would be *very* helpful if you spent a little more time and effort explaining the logic behind this code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a switch is basically identical to a chained if/else - it all gets mapped to the same thing at the byte code level, just a matter of which syntax you like better.

Comment: I'm more worried about readability and debuggability of this code then "efficiency", unless I see profiler data showing that this code is causing an issue.

Comment: For integral types (like `int`, `short`, and, yes, `char`), if the range isn't too big, Java can turn the `switch` statement into a lookup table of places to jump to, *potentially* making it faster.  But til you've profiled it and seen it's faster *in your case*, readability wins out IMO.  Personally, though, i find `switch` statements more readable as well when it involves checking more than one possibility and an `else`.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you can say `case 'K': case 'R': /*dostuff*/ break;` when you have two cases that do the exact same thing.

Comment: If you are that concerned about performance that you're drilling down to `if` vs. `switch`, then why aren't you caching the results of `protein.getSeq()` and especially `protein.getSeq().charAt(...)` instead of calling them multiple times across the `case`s and `||`s?

Comment: honestly wasn't sure if allocating new memory would slow it down more than pulling the char out for each use--havent had much formal CS education. My main objective is speed and this method gets called thousands of times for one protein out of tens of thousands. For this stage of the program it's actually a more time consuming part and small changes could mean minutes depending on the database. @HovercraftFullOfEels w/o a specific question it'd be hard to explain more w/o talking chemistry and giving more details on a program my lab may end up selling. thanks 4 the hashmap and profiler tips!

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing is what we'd call a micro-optimization.

Using a `switch` instead of an `if` chain may be beneficial ... or it may not.  It very much depends on the context.

The only way to be sure is to carefully benchmark the code, comparing the versions with and without the potential optimization.  It is also a good idea to profile *first* so that you don't waste time optimizing code that doesn't really matter.

Note that the effects of a given micro-optimization *may* vary depending on your actual execution hardware, Operating System and JVM version / flavour.  (And possibly other things too ... like how much physical memory is available and how big the heap is.)  Predicting the benefits from first principles is hard, and it is always possible that a platform change can negate all of your hand tuning work.